# CoreBluetooth cannot be found when I use my Android device as ibeacon using AltBeacon

Tags: android, swift, core-bluetooth, beacon

I have Ibeacon scanning app which use CoreBluetooth. I want to use my real android device as an beacon. I can scan my Ibeacons but can not found my android device.

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth 

public class BeaconScanning: NSObject, BKCentralDelegate{
  let central = BKCentral()

  override init(){

    super.init()
    central.delegate = self
    do {
      let serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: "FF80") // For my used Ibeacon Service Data
      let characteristicUUID = CBUUID( )
      let configuration = BKConfiguration(dataServiceUUID: serviceUUID, dataServiceCharacteristicUUID: characteristicUUID)  // Configration for scanning
      try central.startWithConfiguration(configuration)
    } catch let error { }

    central.scanContinuouslyWithChangeHandler({ changes, discoveries in }, stateHandler: { newState in }, duration: 2, inBetweenDelay: 0.1, beaconHandler: { beacons in

      for beacon in beacons! {

         // get beacons properties

      }

    }, errorHandler: { error in })

  }

  public func central(_ central: BKCentral, remotePeripheralDidDisconnect remotePeripheral: BKRemotePeripheral) {

  } 
}
```

I can scan my Ibeacon devices in IOS app. But, it cannot be found when I use my Android device as Ibeacon using AltBeacon.

```
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder().  
                .setId1("e2c56db5-dffb-48d2-b060-d0f5a71096e0") //uuid the same my Ibeacon
                .setId2("0") 
                .setId3("0")
                .setManufacturer(0x0118)
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
                .build();
        BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"); //altbeacon layout for parser transmitting as a beacon 
        BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
        beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be able to find Becons with CoreBluetooth, use CoreLocation for that. Because when iOS sees a BLE device advertising as a iBeacon, it doesn't give it to CoreBluetooth, but to CoreLocation.

Comment: @Larme I can scan the ibeacons with the IOS code I gave above and get the RSSI values in certain period time using CBUUID(string: "FF80"). But when ı want to scan android device (act an ibeacon) ı cant.

Comment: Scanning for "FF80" shouldn't let you find "pure" iBeacon. And you should find device only if they decide to advertise it. Maybe if you tell us what's `BKConfiguration`, since it seems to be able to scan with Service UUID & Charecteristic UUID (which aren't advertised).

Comment: @Larme ı used CoreLocation to find android device (act an ibeacon). CoreLocation also find ibeacon but not find android device. But the other Locata App in my ıos device find my android device  as an ibeacon with it's RSSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CoreLocation:

```
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setManufacturer(0x004c) // Use Ibeacon Manufacturer
                .setId1("e2c56db5-dffb-48d2-b060-d0f5a71096e0")
                .setId2("0")
                .setId3("0")
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
                .build();
        BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");//BeaconLayout startwith ("m:2-3=0215)
        BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
        beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```